# How do I create timeseries CSV from state dumps in postgresql

Tags: postgresql

Given this data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE foo(
  ts BIGINT NOT NULL
  data JSONB NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO foo VALUES
  (0, '[{"host": "alice", "value": 10}, {"host": "bob", "value": 5}]'), 
  (60, '[{"host": "alice", "value": 20}, {"host": "bob", "value": 6}]');
```

How do I create a CSV output something like:

```sql
Time,Alice,Bob
0,10,5
60,20,6
```

Note that I don't know at query time about "alice" and "bob".

I tried `crosstab`, e.g.:

```sql
CREATE VIEW foo_elems AS
SELECT
  ts,
  elem->>'host' AS host,
  elem->>'value' AS value
FROM (
  SELECT
    ts,
    jsonb_array_elements(data) AS elem
  FROM foo) as elems;

SELECT * from crosstab('SELECT * FROM foo_elems') AS ct(ts BIGINT, alice TEXT, bob TEXT);
```

Output:

```
 ts | alice | bob 
----+-------+-----
  0 | 10    | 5
 60 | 20    | 6
```

The only thing wrong with that query is that I have to hardcode the number of hosts, and their names (and that it seems crosstab only supports a limited number of columns).

I realize I can easily do this externally with code, assembling the CSV timeline as it comes, and then add the header up top when all has been streamed, but I'm hoping to keep as much logic in the database as possible.

I expect the number of hosts to be managable. Like 10-20.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One fundamental restriction of a SQL query is, that the number, names and data types of all columns of a query must be known before the query is executed (when it's parsed). So there is no workaround for hardcoding the column names.

But typically this is a lot easier to do with conditional aggregation rather than using the clumsy

```
select f.ts,
       sum((item  ->> 'value')::int) filter (where d.item ->> 'host' = 'alice') as alice,
       sum((item  ->> 'value')::int) filter (where d.item ->> 'host' = 'bob') as bob
from foo f
  cross join jsonb_array_elements(data) as d(item)
group by f.ts
order by f.ts;
```

---

If the number of hosts doesn't change very often, you might think about a stored procedure that dynamically generates a view for all available hosts on a regular basis. Something along  the lines:

```sql
do
$$
declare
 l_columns text;
 l_sql text;
begin
 
  select string_agg(format('sum((item ->> ''value'')::int) filter (where d.item ->> ''host'' = %L) as %I', host, host), ', ')
    into l_columns
  from (
    select distinct item ->> 'host' as host
    from foo f
      cross join jsonb_array_elements(data) as d(item)
  ) t;

  l_sql := 'create view host_csv as select f.ts, '||l_columns||' from foo f cross join jsonb_array_elements(f.data) as d(item) group by f.ts';
  execute l_sql;
end;
$$;
```

[Online example](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=57c17bb3e58faed3e0213909300bfbaa)

Comment: It's not possible with colums, but could there be some solution with arrays?

Comment: Not sure how an array would help. How would you know which array element belongs to which host? I would probably simplify the original JSON in the first place, so that it's not an array but contains the host names directly as keys, e.g. `{"bob": 5, "alice": 20}`